# Filling an Array with Random numbers, but the rand-Method doesnt work fast enough?

Tags: c#, random, random-seed

I try to fill array by random [-1,0,1] like this, but outputs like that: -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
So it changes to slow? Do i have to set a new seed every time?

```
Random rnd = new Random();

            int z = rnd.Next(2);
            z -= 1;
            int q = rnd.Next(2);
            q -= 1;
```

Comment: _Do i have to set a new seed every time?_ On the contrary!! If you do the result will NOT be random!

Comment: There's no array in what you show here.

Comment: Thanks, the question has been answered before - I'm still figuring out how to use method "StaticRandom" in the article.

Comment: _I'm still figuring out how to use method "StaticRandom" in the article_ Ignore it! - The 1st paragraph is really all you need: Stick to one Random object for all your numbers!